# StandardServiceRegistryBuilder not working in Hibernate 4.3.2

Tags: java, hibernate

I have read StandardServiceRegistryBuilder related posts on SO, but it doesn't seem to solve my problem. This is the code that I am trying to run:

```
   import javax.imageio.spi.ServiceRegistry;
   import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
   import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

   public class TestHibernate {   
      public static void main(String args[]){
         UserDetails userDetails = new UserDetails();
         userDetails.setAge(22);
         userDetails.setName("Saurabh");

         Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
         configuration.configure();
    
         StandardServiceRegistryBuilder serviceRegistryBuilder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder(); //this is where i get error
         serviceRegistryBuilder.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());

         ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = serviceRegistryBuilder.build();
         SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

This is the error given by netbeans:

```
cannot find symbol
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: which symbol it is not finding ?

Comment: @JigarJoshi: class StandardServiceRegistryBuilder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You imported incorrect class, you need

```
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
```

Comment: tried: ide says org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder; doesnt exist

Comment: Add required jar in your classpath

Comment: Which jar is the required jar?  I am running into the same issue, and I have the hibernate.jar added, I was just wondering if there was another that was needed for this.